# Question marks in project navigator Xcode 5

Tags: ios, git, xcode5

i just updated to `Xcode` 5 and my project is using `GIT`, after update completed suddenly question marks appear in project navigator file near each file.

[image]

when i am trying to `Commit` i don't see what files have been changed, i cannot pull also
and when i am trying to push it gives :Push Success" message but the repository on `GitHub` don't updated.

Comment: Are you adding the files to the index? Describe what you're doing...

Comment: Have you tried just quitting XCode and reopening it?

Comment: yes i have tried to quit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably did not set up your git repository properly.  There are ways of adding external git repositories, but they tend not to work well for github (in my experience) and always lead to these sorts of issues.

If you want to set up a remote git repository through github on XCode these are the steps you should take.

1. Make the repository on github.  Make sure to add the .gitignore file for Objective-C.
2. Clone the repository.
3. Go to XCode, press "create new project"
4. Create the project in the folder you cloned the repo to.  I always name it the exact same thing, but I don't know if that is necessary.
5. Make sure not to select create local git repository.

This will definitely create a project that is under version control by a remote git repository hosted on github.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is to Create or Save the new project 'outside' the directory (say Desktop) that is not linked to your github/bitbucket